# Empty or too short HTTP Message

Tags: php, http, httprequest, pecl

I'm having this same issue in my code, but I'm not passing addPostFile method. So I was wondering if I need to pass some others configuration to the request object.

Any idea?

Here is my code

```
$request = new HttpRequest($myURL, HttpRequest::METH_GET);
$request->setBody('');
$request->addQueryData(
    array(
        'service' => 'delete',
        'data' => $dataSend
    ));
$request->send();
```

Comment: This question sounds like an answer that was ported over to a question. Please reword it if you want to receive any decent help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the `$request->setBody('');` You're making a get request and should not have a body to the request.
2. Make sure `$dataSend` isn't null `$dataSend = is_null($dataSend)? "":dataSend`